# convert a grayscale image into 3 channel image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I want to convert a gray-scale image dataset with shape (height,width) to a 3 channels image dataset with shape (height,width,3), i used the solution posted here [convert a grayscale image to a 3-channel image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119743/convert-a-grayscale-image-to-a-3-channel-image) and it gives the following error :

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-f7b70a125ab8> in <module>()
      1 X_mult = mult_imgs(X)
----> 2 plot_samples(X_mult, n=10)

6 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/image.py in set_data(self, A)
    697                 or self._A.ndim == 3 and self._A.shape[-1] in [3, 4]):
    698             raise TypeError("Invalid shape {} for image data"
--> 699                             .format(self._A.shape))
    700 
    701         if self._A.ndim == 3:

TypeError: Invalid shape (77, 77, 3, 3) for image data
```

the complete code is:

```
def load_data(dir_path):
    X = []
    for file in tqdm((os.listdir(dir_path))):
        if not file.startswith('.'):
            img = cv2.imread(dir_path + '//' + file)
            X.append(img)
    X = np.array(X)
    print(f'{len(X)} images loaded from {dir_path} directory.')
    return X

dir_path = '/content/drive/My Drive/oskar'
X = load_data(dir_path)


def plot_samples(X, n=50):
    """
    Creates a gridplot for desired number of images (n) from the specified set
    """
    np.random.shuffle(X)
    imgs = X[:n]
    j = 10
    i = int(n/j)

    plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
    c = 1
    for img in imgs:
        plt.subplot(i,j,c)
        plt.imshow(img)

        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        c += 1
    plt.show()

plot_samples(X, n=30)


def mult_imgs(set_name):
    """
    Convert one channel images to 3 channels
    """
    set_new = []
    for img in set_name:
        new_img = np.stack((img,)*3, axis=-1) 
        #new_img = np.stack((img,) * 3), axis=1)
        set_new.append(new_img)
    return np.array(set_new) 


X_mult = mult_imgs(X)
plot_samples(X_mult, n=10)
```

am using google colab, that's why the call function just after function declaration.
the error appears when executing the last function.
someone can Help me please!

Comment: cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

Comment: @AlexAlex i tried it and it gave the following error: Invalid number of channels in input image:
>     'VScn::contains(scn)'
> where
>     'scn' is 3

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your grayscale image is not of shape `(width,height)`, but is a regular rgb image with just all channels having the same intensities, threfore being of shape `(width,height,3)`.

The code of the answer you are using assumes you have an grayscale image of shape `(width, height)`, but as your image has an extra dimension, it results in a shape `(77, 77, 3, 3)`, which is invalid. You could just remove the extra dimension like this:

```
img = img[:,:,0]
```

In your first function, then you can propably apply the answer you've linked without any problem.

Alternatively load your image as a grayscale image in the first place when calling OpenCV, default is RGB:

```
img = cv2.imread(dir_path + '//' + file, 0)
```

Comment: the images are of shape (width,height) but as you said OpenCV change their shape, so the solution is to add  ``` img = img[:,:,0] ``` or simply add cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED to the imread function